# How Prim's algorithm time complexity is ElogV using Priority Q?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, prims-algorithm

Pseudo code which I used:

```
for all V vertices: visited[n]=0

pick any vertex r from graph and set visited[r]=1

For all edges e incident to r
PQ.insert()

while(PQ is not empty)//line 1
  f=PQ.min()//f(r,s) is such that visited[s]=0
  for all edges e(s,t) incident to s//line 2
     if(visited[t]==0)
        PQ.insert(e);//line 3
     else
        PQ.delete(e);//line 4
  visited[s]=1;
end while;
```

According to my understanding:

- line 1 : executes `V-1` times.
- Line 2 : Sum of Degree of all the vertices times…..that is `2E` times

For each line 2: 
Line 3 and line 4 take `log E` time because we’re adding/deleting all the edges to/from the `PQ` one by one.

So total `time`= `V-1+2E.logE` = `E.log E`

But the book says it is `E.logV`, could you explain why that is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O(log(V)) and O(log(E)) are the same.

- E is at most V<sup>2</sup>.
- log(V<sup>2</sup>) = 2*log(V)
- which is an O(log(V))

Comment: @Nick D: right, but as I think in complexities, for me it's the same. E is at most O(V^2) :)

Answer (score 1):

> for all edges e(s,t) incident to s

How many edges a node `s` can have at most?
`V-1` at most. So, PQ operations have O(logV) time complexity.

Comment: True...got it.
Thank u so much :)